# How to use a List in a Row FLutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I tried using a List I had already created with a row but I kept getting this error `lib/main.dart:94:21: Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.`

`- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.`

`- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'`

`('/C:/fluttersdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').`

`children: scoreKeeper,`

[Using the list with my Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkOEH.png)

[Creating List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axs68.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `scoreKeeper` variable to be of type `List<Widget>` instead of just `List`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

Define list as List scoreKeeper in main.dart.